# PHP How to echo a different image every 10th row of my results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, echo, counter

I have a simple search engine which echo's out results in a table with CSS formatting, this is working fine, however, i would now like to echo a different image after every 10 results.

thankyou to any one who can help me as I have been stuck on this for hours!

this is my echo output code:

```
echo "<table width='50%' style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000;'";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<div id='page-wrap'>";
echo "<div class='discounted-item freeshipping'>";

echo "<a href='./img/users/" . $row['category'] . "/" . $row['username'] . "/" . $row['filename'] . "' rel='lightbox'><img src=\"./img/users/" . $row['category'] . "/" . $row['username'] . "/" . $row['filename'] . "\" alt=\"\" width='20%' height='98%' /></a>";


echo "<div class='reasonbar'><div class='prod-title' style='width: 70%;'>" .$row['fname'] . "</div><div class='reason' style='width: 29%;'><b>". $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['surname'] ."</b></div></div>";

echo "<div class='reasonbar'><div class='prod-title1' style='width: 70%;'>" . $row['lname'] . "</div><div class='reason1' style='width: 29%;'>Category: ". $row['category'] . "</div></div>";

echo "<div class='reasonbar'><div class='prod-title2' style='width: 70%;'>Contact:" . $row['contact'] . "</div><div class='reason2' style='width: 29%;'>Price: &pound;". $row['price'] . "</div></div>";


echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
}

}

else
    echo "No results found for \"<b>$search</b>\"";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use modolus operator to determine that...

```
if ( ! ($i % 10)) {
    // Alternate.
}
```

If you don't have a counter variable at your disposal, just declare one outside of your loop and set it to `0` and increment it for each iteration.

Comment: thanks for your reply! at which point in the echo code would i place this?

Comment: @NeilKumar The condition can be calculated anywhere, but it seems probably you'll want to place it where you want to echo the alternate image.

Comment: I'm a bit stuck on how to declare the counter, i think its with $i++; ? but not sure where to place it and how this would count the number of results

Comment: `$i = 0` outside of your loop and `$i++` inside your loop after you've read its value in the condition.